# R Side-by-side grouped boxplot

Tags: r, colors, legend, boxplot

I have temporal data of gas emissions from two species of plant, both of which have been subjected to the same treatments. With some [previous help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848186/unify-boxplot-factor-group-colours/23848829#23848829) to get this code together [edit]:

```
soilflux = read.csv("soil_fluxes.csv") 
library(ggplot2)
soilflux$Treatment <- factor(soilflux$Treatment,levels=c("L-","C","L+"))
soilplot = ggplot(soilflux, aes(factor(Week), Flux, fill=Species, alpha=Treatment)) + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + geom_boxplot()
soilplot = soilplot + labs(x = "Week", y = "Flux (mg m-2 d-1)") + theme_bw(base_size = 12, base_family = "Helvetica")
soilplot
```

Producing this which works well but has its flaws.

[image: img]

Whilst it conveys all the information I need it to, despite Google trawls and looking through here I just couldn't get the 'Treatment' part of the legend to show that L- is light and L+ darkest. I've also been told that a monochrome colour scheme is easier to differentiate hence I'm trying to get something like [this](https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/figures/1471-2288-9-6-2-l.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/9/6/figure/F2?highres=y&h=873&w=1200&tbnid=ZFSIdTwmEP3B-M:&zoom=1&docid=x-wdYI08P9VpZM&ei=kUZbVPOkAYfhatG3gfgP&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu&ved=0CGMQMyg8MDw&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=495&page=3&start=41&ndsp=23) where the legend is clear.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [biomedcentral.com](https://www.biomedcentral.com/content/figures/1471-2288-9-6-2-l.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you could create a combined factor from `species` and `treatment` and assign the fill colors manually:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
d <- expand.grid(week = factor(1:4), species = factor(c("Heisteria", "Simarouba")),
                 trt = factor(c("C", "L-", "L+"), levels = c("L-", "C", "L+")))

d <- d[rep(1:24, each = 30), ]
d$flux <- runif(NROW(d))

# Create a combined factor for coding the color
d$spec.trt <- interaction(d$species, d$trt, lex.order = TRUE, sep = " - ")

ggplot(d, aes(x = week, y = flux, fill = spec.trt)) +
   stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + geom_boxplot() +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(3, "Greens"), brewer.pal(3, "Reds")))
```

[image: grouped boxplot]

Comment: I tend to agree that mixing the two scales into one might actually be a better solution. Using discrete alpha values (more than 2) combined with different colors makes it hard for the eye to compare and find out which levels match together, etc. Moreover, the unique scale displays all possible color combinations wheareas the 2-scale solution doesn't.

Comment: You are more than welcome. If it works, can you also accept the answer please?