# Scatterplot with categorical x-axis (and uncertainties boxes) in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, boxplot

I have made some calculations on data measured on several systems of photovoltaic panels. I have 11 different photovoltaic systems, and for each of them I have 3 different numerical values.

My results are in a matrix that has 11 rows (each of them corresponding to one of the photovoltaic systems), and 3 columns (containing the 3 numerical quantities computed for each system).

Here is a minimal reproducible matrix :

```
            monthly_LR monthly_CSD monthly_HW
solon            0.398       0.417       0.48
sanyo            0.489       0.479       0.59
atersa              NA          NA         NA
sunpower         0.129          NA       0.19
schott_efg       0.387       0.486       0.47
BP               0.235       0.161       0.22
solarworld       1.153       1.245       1.25
schott_main      0.531       0.628       0.62
wurth            2.889       2.886       2.85
first            1.631       1.651       1.64
mhi              0.974       0.888       1.02
```

and the corresponding `dput` output so you can reproduce it :

```
structure(c(0.398, 0.489, NA, 0.129, 0.387, 0.235, 1.153, 0.531, 
2.889, 1.631, 0.974, 0.417, 0.479, NA, NA, 0.486, 0.161, 1.245, 
0.628, 2.886, 1.651, 0.888, 0.48, 0.59, NA, 0.19, 0.47, 0.22, 
1.25, 0.62, 2.85, 1.64, 1.02), .Dim = c(11L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("solon", "sanyo", "atersa", "sunpower", "schott_efg", "BP", 
"solarworld", "schott_main", "wurth", "first", "mhi"), c("monthly_LR", 
"monthly_CSD", "monthly_HW")))    `
```

I also have **another matrix which contains the uncertainties** associated with each value of the first matrix :

```
           monthly_LR_uncertainty    monthly_CSD_uncertainty  monthly_HW_uncertainty
solon                        0.14                    0.09                    0.07
sanyo                        0.13                    0.06                    0.07
atersa                         NA                    0.13                      NA
sunpower                     0.18                    0.18                    0.20
schott_efg                   0.14                    0.07                    0.06
BP                           0.14                    0.14                    0.15
solarworld                   0.16                    0.04                    0.03
schott_main                  0.15                    0.08                    0.07
wurth                        0.12                    0.10                    0.11
first                        0.08                    0.09                    0.10
mhi                          0.08                    0.07                    0.08
```

and the corresponding `dput` output so you can reproduce it :

```
structure(c(0.14, 0.13, NA, 0.18, 0.14, 0.14, 0.16, 0.15, 0.12, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.06, 0.13, 0.18, 0.07, 0.14, 0.04, 0.08, 0.1, 
0.09, 0.07, 0.07, 0.07, NA, 0.2, 0.06, 0.15, 0.03, 0.07, 0.11, 
0.1, 0.08), .Dim = c(11L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("solon", "sanyo", 
"atersa", "sunpower", "schott_efg", "BP", "solarworld", "schott_main", 
"wurth", "first", "mhi"), c("monthly_LR_uncertainty", "monthly_CSD_uncertainty", 
"monthly_HW_uncertainty")))    `
```

Now, here is the type of scatterplot I would like to obtain (I almost got what I wanted with boxplots, but now I'd prefer a scatterplot) :

I would like the x-axis to be categorical, as it is when I make a boxplot (i.e. one category for each of the 11 rows).

And above each category on the x-axis, I would like to have 3 points corresponding to the 3 values in the corresponding row of the first matrix, with boxes indicating the uncertainty on the results.

The image below (a graph in an article written by a researcher of the same lab than me, but that is gone from the lab now) shows exactly what I want to obtain. The 11 categories on the x-axis correspond to my 11 rows. The three different points for each category (blue, red, green) correspond to the 3 values for each category in the first matrix. And the box associated to each point corresponds to the uncertainty (given in the second matrix).

[image]

Comment: You probably want error bars

Comment: Yes, that's error bars on a scatterplot that I want, and the values of the errors are contained in my second matrix. But even besides that, I don't know how to obtain the scatterplot without the error bars.

Comment: For this to be reproducible please provide the data in a reproducible way, such as `dput`. Or show the code to create the matrices. There's a way to get the data in R from the clipboard but it's heavily unreliable.

Comment: OK sorry, I thought that presenting the data like this in my post was enough for other people to be able to reproduce my matrices. I will work on it and edit my post.

Comment: Done ! Below each of my 2 matrices, I have added the corresponding dput output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `a` is the table with means and `b` is the table with uncertainties:

```
# x axis width
x = 1:nrow(a)

# horizontal offset for data of same group
offset = 0.2

# draw empty plot
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0, nrow(a)), ylim=c(0, max(a,na.rm=T)), xaxt='n', ylab='performance', xlab='')

# add error bars (arrows with angle=90)
arrows(x0=x, x1=x, y0 = a[,1]-0.5*b[,1], y1 = a[,1]+0.5*b[,1], angle=90, code=3, len=0.01)
arrows(x0=x-offset, x1=x-offset, y0 = a[,2]-0.5*b[,2], y1 = a[,2]+0.5*b[,2], angle=90, code=3, col=2, len=0.02)
arrows(x0=x+offset, x1=x+offset, y0 = a[,3]-0.5*b[,3], y1 = a[,3]+0.5*b[,3], angle=90, code=3, col=4, len=0.02)

# add points
points(x, a[,1], pch=1, col=1)
points(x-offset, a[,2], pch=2, col=2)
points(x+offset, a[,3], pch=3, col=4)

# axis labels
axis(1, at = 1:nrow(a), labels = rownames(a), las=3)

# add legend
legend(x='topleft', legend=colnames(a), col=c(1,2,4), pch=c(1,2,3), inset=0.02)
```

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26781865/2516066) answer for grouped boxplots.